# Exception during discrete event: Can't set arrival callback during movement

Tags: anylogic

I am encountering this error in the image while running the simulation, I am not sure where that agent is or  how to find it as its a really huge model. Please can someone help me with understanding what does that error mean and how to get rid of it

Unfortunately it is not the same agent every time

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOnyf.png)

Comment: very hard to say, probably best to scale back the model and see when it stops popping up...

Answer (score 1):

one of the reasons, i don't know if the only one for which this error can occur is when you are trying to move an agent to 2 different places (or even to the same place) at the same time..

So for example if you have a moveTo block and on the onEnter action you do agent.moveTo(somewhere) you will get this error.

It seems in your case that the error occurs rarely because you probably have different moveTo in different situations that occur at the same time in very rare occassions, so I can only tell you to investigate this carefully and remove any chance you are giving different moving instructions to agents at the same time, even if the destination is the same.